# android clickable - leaves shape around button background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-button

Could anyone please help me with this.

My buttons all have background images, which work fine and look good. The only problem is, when I enable them and make them enabled, they have weird areas around them. The areas are transparent but there borders aint.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have played with both "Clickable" and "Enabled". It turns out it is the enabled option that makes the weird area.

Comment: It is now sorted. If anyone else has this problem adding >>>style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" . to the xml of the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where a section was transparent but the border was not. Figured out to be a jquery ui-dialog box border. You can try checking which CSS class is causing the issue and add this to the CSS class:

outline: 0;

Comment: I am not sure where this would go?

Comment: pressed enter to quickly: <head><style> .ui-dialog {outline: 0;} <\style><\head>. you will have to identify the css class (.ui-dialog) and add the property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am writing in XML so writing style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" worked a treat.